# Error calculating intersection between Polygon and Multipolygon

Tags: r, r-sf

I am running into an issue calculating the intersection polygon between a Polygon and a Multipolygon as so:

```
st_intersection(poly1,poly2)
```

This command gets the error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, attr(x, "sf_column"), value = list( : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

poly1 looks like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -75.81667 ymin: -11.00833 xmax: -69.825 ymax: -3.016667
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
                        geometry
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.69167 -...
```

poly2 looks like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -74.5 ymin: -5 xmax: -74 ymax: -4.5
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
                        geometry
1 POLYGON ((-74.5 -4.5, -74 -...
```

Converting poly2 to a Multipolygon does not solve the issue. Creating a second regular, simple Polygon and calling an intersection between it and poly2 works just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: At the request of @user2554330, I will try to supply more code to create the polygons:

poly1: Unfortunately this comes from a larger dataset, but I can try to give more information still. It is a Large sfc_MULTIPOLYGON--I am wondering if the largeness is the problem. It looks like this: [image]

poly2: Can be created with this code

```
lon <- c(b_xmin,b_xmax)
lat <- c(b_ymin,b_ymax)
Poly_Coord_df = data.frame(lon, lat)
pol = st_polygon(
  list(
    cbind(
      Poly_Coord_df$lon[c(1,2,2,1,1)], 
      Poly_Coord_df$lat[c(1,1,2,2,1)])
      )
  )
poly2 = st_sfc(pol, crs=4326)
```

Comment: Please add some code to create `poly1` and `poly2`, so that others can help.

Comment: "Can be created with this code" - you need to tell us what `b_xmin, b_xmax, etc` are otherwise we can't create `poly2`.

Comment: And does the error occur with simply intersecting the first row of the `MULTIPOLYGON` object? If so can you gives us the output of `dput(poly1[1, "geometry")` ? Or even a very simple MULTIPOLYGON object that replicates the issue. Otherwise it's very hard to help without any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to not be able to have provided more help in my question, but, having resolved it, I will quickly post my solution in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future. I found `st_intersection()` worked when I replaced `poly1`, the Multipolygon, with `poly1[[2]]`. It returned the output as a Polygon and a Multilinestring.